# Access ForgotPasswordController when authorized

Tags: laravel

I am not very good at English so not sure if I can explain my status correctly.

Currently, I am building admin panel which allow users to reset their password. So in the admin panel, I select user and click 'reset password' button. Then, resetPassword notification email will be sent to specific users(by email).

I am trying to do this with ForgorPasswordController's sendResetLinkEmail function but it seems I can't access their once authorized.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't (and probably shouldn't) use that controller.

It will be easier to create new controller for your admin panel page and use the built in helper:
https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.html#method_sendResetLink

That should be available through `Password` facade

```
use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
(...)

Password::sendResetLink($emailAddress, function (Message $message) {
        $message->subject('Password Reset');
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks.     public function resetPassword(Request $request) {
      $emailAddress = $request['email'];

      Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
        $message->subject('Password Reset');
      });
    }

Comment: Glad it works. And also welcome to the Stackoverflow community! :)